# Can laptop display 144Hz on extern display?

Tags: display

I have a MSi GE70, and I think the screen can display 60FPS max, then 60Hz.
But I would like to buy a 24' 144Hz, and I was wondering if I plug it with HDMI or DVI, the external monitor can display the 144Hz, or the laptop will limit 60Hz ?

Comment: I think you first need to consider what game you want to play at 120+ fps. Will the video card in a laptop be able to render frames fast enough for the investment in the monitor to be worth it?

Comment: @LittleHelper There are all sorts of questions here about connecting consoles to various kinds of displays, I don't know if PCs should considered differently. The MSI GE70 is a gaming laptop, and 144Hz displays are sold as gaming monitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your laptop is not limited to 60hz, your laptop's *screen* might be, but as long as your laptop can correctly connect to the monitor in question you should be fine...

My own 120hz monitor requires me to use dual-link DVI cable to display full 120hz (and 120fps) - I'm 90% sure that HDMI cannot send more than a 60hz signal so that wouldn't work for you.

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: While HDMI is only single-link it can run that link about twice as fast as single-link DVI. 1920x1080x120Hz is doable over HDMI (it's the same rate as 1080p 60Hz 3D), but it doesn't look like 144Hz is. The original poster's laptop would need an actual DVI connector or a (Mini-) DisplayPort connector to get 144Hz, which it doesn't look like it has.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect monitor using DVI cable, i think it can go up to 144hz. For HDMI, maximum is 120hz.

Reference: https://ibestmarts.com/best-gaming-monitor/